# JQuery Tab Selected If Condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help with JQuery if condition for selected tab. I tried many different ways and googled it but couldn't make it.

I'm using MVC and JQuery. I Have Two Tabs in index.aspx

### Index.aspx

```
<div id="entry-analysis-data-chart-tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a id="cumulative-chart" href="#cumulative-inhome-chart">Cumulative In Home Data Chart</a></li>
            <li><a id="non-cumulative-chart" href="#noncumulative-inhome-chart">In Home Daily Data Chart</a></li>             
        </ul>
        <div id="cumulative-inhome-chart" style="height: 300px;">
            <div id="cumulative-inhome-chart-div" style="width: 480px; padding-left: 0;"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="noncumulative-inhome-chart" style="height: 300px;">
            <div id="noncumulative-inhome-chart-div" style="width: 480px; height: 100%; padding-left: 0;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

---

in JQuery

```
$(config.selectors.$resultsTable).live("click", function () {

        if cumulative-chart Tab is selected I want to execute this function 
        setupCummulativeChart();

        if non-cumulative-chart tab is Selected then I want this function to be executed
        setupNonCummulativeChart();


    });
```

Can you please help me how to do it.

Comment: When you say "when cumulative chart is selected" you mean when you click on it?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(config.selectors.$resultsTable).live("click", function () {
    if( $('#cumulative-inhome-chart').is(':visible') ) {
        // ...
    }
    if( $('#noncumulative-inhome-chart').is(':visible') ) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This works because the tabs that aren't selected have display:none as css property. 
I assume you click on something different, and you want to test which tab is currently selected.

Comment: @Sonny If this answer solved your problem, please mark the answer as "accepted" to close the question.